# update mysqli query with set values

Tags: php, mysqli

I can update my columns dynamically, but I dont know how to update it with set values (stupid I know)

This is my sql code that updates the columns with set values:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET user_deletion_date = NOW(), user_deleted_by = '.$_SESSION['id'].', deleted = Y
          WHERE user_id = ?';
  if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    // bind the query parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['user_id']);
    // bind the result to variables
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user_deletion_date, $user_deleted_by, $deleted);
    // execute the query, and fetch the result
    $done = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
  }
}
if ($done) {
  header('Location: update_users_confirm.php');
  exit;
}
```

this doesn't update the table at all, I know that the issue is with my bind_param, could someone please help

Comment: You are checking both `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Do you have data in both? That is, was the form `action='` like `processform.php?user_id=123`?

Comment: Your prepare/bind/execute/fetch code looks correct otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I post the user_id from a php form, but apart from that the other values are set

Comment: If user_id comes from `<form method='post'>` you need to retrieve it from `$_POST['user_id']` not `$_GET`.  The `$_POST['delete']` implies it is a post.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, and you ought to see undefined index notices.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski just checked it uses get method, I can update it fine with dynamic values using this code. It's quite strange

Comment: if the form uses get instead of post, then the outer condition `if (isset($_POST['delete']))` will fail.  That must be `$_GET`.

Comment: Failing this, post the form's HTML markup too.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for taking time to look into this, I just passed the 'Y' value dynamically from a hidden field, it worked fine :). my problem was not being able to create the query sucessfully with the set values.

Comment: Ah now when I look at it I see it, you needed `deleted = 'Y'` with the Y as a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Michael B's answer is mostly likely the solution. Change the $_GET to $_POST